# How to get value of --limit argument inside an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

In ansible, is it possible to get the value of the argument to the "--limit" option within a playbook? I want to do is something like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote user: root
  tasks:
  - name: The value of the --limit argument
    debug:
      msg: "argument of --limit is {{ ansible-limit-arg }}"
```

Then when I run he command:

```
$ ansible-playbook getLimitArg.yaml --limit webhosts
```

I'll get this output:

```
argument of --limit is webhost
```

Of course, I made up the name of the variable "ansible-limit-arg", but is there a valid way of doing this? I could specify "webhosts" twice, the second time with --extra-args, but that seems a roundabout way of having to do this.

Comment: Why do you need to get this info? The `--limit` option (that can take a list, BTW), will limit the target of your plays. If you really need to know the reduced list, then use the `ansible_play_hosts` variable

Comment: The application this applies to is an SAP HANA database. The host group name for ansible, the argument to the "--limit" option, is the same as the environment name for the database cluster. If I can recover the "--limit" value within the playbook, I don't also have to specify the environment name separately. It's a matter of convenience, but also accuracy if other SysAmins are using my playbooks.

Answer (score 23):

Since Ansible 2.5 you can access the value using a new magic variable `ansible_limit`, so:

```
- debug:
    var: ansible_limit
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the `{{ ansible_play_batch }}` built-in variable?

```
- hosts: all
  become: "False"
  gather_facts: "False"
  tasks:
    - name: The value of the --limit argument
      debug:
        msg: "argument of --limit is {{ ansible_play_batch }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

It won't tell you exactly what was entered as the argument but it will tell you how Ansible interpreted the `--limit` arg.

Comment: I find it interesting that the `ansible_play_batch` or `ansible_play_hosts` magic variable will contain the managed hosts the play is being run against, but `ansible_limit` does not. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without additional plugin/module. If you utterly need this, write action plugin and access options via `cli.options` (see [example](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.1.0-1/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py#L66:L69)).

P.S. If you try to use `--limit` to run playbooks agains different environments, don't do it, you can accidentally blow your whole infrastructure – use different inventories instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small code block to achieve the same

```
- block:
  - shell: 'echo {{inventory_hostname}} >> /tmp/hosts'
  - shell: cat /tmp/hosts
    register: servers
  - file:
      path: /tmp/hosts
      state: absent
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  - debug: var=servers.stdout_lines
```

Then use stdout_lines output as u wish like mine

```
- add_host:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: cluster
    ansible_user: "ubuntu"
  with_items:
    - "{{ servers.stdout_lines }}"
```