# How to detect --limit in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a task which has meaning only if it has been run with full list of hosts (creating a `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file). I want to skip this task if '--limit' has been used.

Is any way in ansible to detect if `--limit` option was used?

Comment: [How to get value of --limit argument inside an Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44855892/2947502)

Answer (score 0):

After some struggles I found a way:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
   - set_fact:
        full_run: '{{play_hosts == groups.all}}'
...
- hosts: other_group
  tasks:
   - template: ...
     when: full_run
```